# How can i render specific chart type when i click buttons?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm new to react.js

I'm trying to make this website :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEwQ6.png)

and what i want to do is when i click type in the Menu and the chart in container should be changed to exact type.
so I wrote code like this :

```js
  const [showChart, setShowChart] = useState(false);
  const [showChart1, setShowChart1] = useState(false);
  const [showChart2, setShowChart2] = useState(false);
  const [showChart3, setShowChart3] = useState(false);
  const Click = e => {
    switch (e.currentTarget.id) {
      case "one":
        setShowChart(true);
        break;
      case "two":
        setShowChart1(true);
        break;
      case "three":
        setShowChart2(true);
        break;
      case "four":
        setShowChart3(true);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <button>Line</button>
        <button>Bar</button>
        <button>Pie</button>
        <button>Radar</button>
      </div>
      <MainContainer>
        <SideContainer id="one" onClick={Click}>
          {showChart && (
            <Bar
              data={data}
              options={{ responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }}
            />
          )}
        </SideContainer>
```

and what should i learn for making this thing??  help me please ☹

Comment: How are you using the showChart1, showChart2 etc states? This seems to be redundant and unnecessary. You might be able to instead return the id as the value of the showChart state instead of a boolean.

Comment: And based on the script above, the onclick function should be applied to the buttons, not to the slider.

Comment: I'm using the `showChart1` etc for showing Bar chart in `<SideContainer>`

Comment: How can i do return the id ??